# Is it possible to show Toast message or Pop Up on click of Image in android?

Tags: android, popup, toast

I am creating an application in which I want to Toast a message or show popup on Image click.

Note : I don't want to show Toast or popup using ImageButton, ImageView or Button.

Please Answer with code

Code :

I want to event happen on myImage object

private Map map;

```
private ImageButton button;

private SupportMapFragment mapFragment = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
    boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(
            getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + ".here-maps",
            "");

    mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(
                OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
            if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                // now the map is ready to be used
                map = mapFragment.getMap();

              //  map.setZoomLevel(12);
                // ...

                com.here.android.mpa.common.Image myImage =
                        new com.here.android.mpa.common.Image();



                button = new ImageButton(MainActivity.this);
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_name);

                try {
                    myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_name);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                                    map.addMapOverlay(
                        new MapOverlay(button,
                                new GeoCoordinate(49.203076, -123.133849, 0.0)));


                // Set the map center to Vancouver, Canada.
                map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(49.203076, -123.133849), Map.Animation.NONE);



                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Harish",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

// Create a custom marker image

```
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize SupportMapFragment");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can set OnClickListener to imageView and show toast or popup inside onClick method.

Comment: It's not ImageView its only Image

Comment: Doesn't it too silly question? You need to perform same click event as you want to perform for imageview.

Comment: Bro Have you ever tried it before telling silly question and if tried then show me ScreenShot

Comment: Which part are you asking about, exactly? How to display that image? How to show the `Toast` upon clicking it? Or both?

Comment: Only Toast but please note I'm neither using ImageButton nor ImageView
e.g private Image = img; 
and I'm able to show image using img object.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us exactly how you're displaying that `Image`.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it :

```
yourImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(GroupProfile.this, "Your Toast here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        });
```

Comment: leave a comment if you have query or please appreciate the answer if it helps you

Comment: It's not ImageView its only Image and with Image object doesn't have any method as setOnClickListener

Comment: bhut easy h jaise btn pr click lgate ho waise hi image pr click lgega

Comment: bro code daal diya hai thoda complicated tha issiliye nahi daal rha tha

Comment: myImage pr clickListner lgana h kya

Comment: ha but  setOnclickListener nahi aa rha h aur mai kr rha hu to error aa rha h method ka

Comment: collage ka assignment h kya ye ?

Comment: ImageView nahi h ye . Ye to map ka kuch lg rha h

Comment: or tum yha pr click nahi lga skte

Answer (score 0):

You can first detect whether you have touch your image or not using onTouch event and display your message using toast method.
It will look something like this.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
int action = event.getAction();
int x = event.getX()  
int y = event.getY();

switch(action){
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    if (x >= xOfYourBitmap && x < (xOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getWidth())
            && y >= yOfYourBitmap && y < (yOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getHeight())) {
        //tada, if this is true, you've started your click inside your bitmap
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is my Toast message!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: bhai only click lgana h koi ram khani nahi likhni

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you use ImageView instead of android.media.image. There is no methods like OnClickListener() for android.media.image...

Another solution is to follow the answer given by Chetan Mehara https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725131/chetan-mehra  which is as follows

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
  int action = event.getAction();
  int x = event.getX()  
  int y = event.getY();

  switch(action){
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      if (x >= xOfYourBitmap && x < (xOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getWidth())
        && y >= yOfYourBitmap && y < (yOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getHeight())) {
        //tada, if this is true, you've started your click inside your bitmap
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is my Toast message!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }
      break;
   }
}
```